# Android Volley Library with GSON not able to set data to POJO classes

Tags: java, android, android-volley, android-json, gson

I want to parse below `json` by using **Gson Library**, from last two hours i'm trying the get data in the POJO classes respective to below json.

I already created POJO/Model classes for below JSON by using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ , but i'm not able to parse it  by using GSON.

**My JSON :**

```
{
"SKU": [
    "Hydrangea White( F033 )",
    "Pink Rose 50 cm( F075 )",
    "Yellow Rose 50 cm( F074 )",
    "White Rose 50 cm( F072 )",

],
"wherehouse3": {
    "name": "New Jersey",
    "data": [
        20,
        14.583333333333,
        13.541666666667,
        12.5,

    ],
    "qty": {
        "Hydrangea White( F033 )": 70,
        "Pink Rose 50 cm( F075 )": 50,
        "Yellow Rose 50 cm( F074 )": 50,
        "White Rose 50 cm( F072 )": 25,

    },
    "cunsumption_time": {
        "Hydrangea White( F033 )": 0,
        "Pink Rose 50 cm( F075 )": 0,
        "Yellow Rose 50 cm( F074 )": 0,
        "White Rose 50 cm( F072 )": 0,

    },
    "sold_qty": {
        "Hydrangea White( F033 )": 480,
        "Pink Rose 50 cm( F075 )": 350,
        "Yellow Rose 50 cm( F074 )": 325,
        "White Rose 50 cm( F072 )": 300,

    },
    "projected_inventry": [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,

    ],
    "recived_inventry": [
        1120,
        525,
        2953,
        900,

    ],
    "sku": [
        "F033",
        "F075",
        "F074",
        "F072",

    ],
    "productname": [
        "Hydrangea White",
        "Pink Rose 50 cm",
        "Yellow Rose 50 cm",
        "White Rose 50 cm",

    ]
  }
 }
```

When i am trying with below code its throws an exception

> Exception: org.json.JSONException: No value for list

**FRAGMENT CODE :**

```
private static final int MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS = 60000;
List<HighVelocityPojo> mList;

private void JsonRequestGraph() {

    utils.showDialog();

    String url = Constants.TOP_10_BOUQUIT+"days="+time+"&warehouse_id="+whareHouse;
    Log.e("URL", "" + url);

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e("onResponse",""+response);
                    try {
                            String info = response.getString("list");
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(info);

                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<HighVelocityPojo>>() {
                            }.getType();
                            mList = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), listType);

                            callGraphView();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Exception",""+e); //Here getting Exception , org.json.JSONException: No value for list
                        utils.hideDialog();
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                   utils.hideDialog();




                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Log.e("error",""+error.getMessage());
            utils.hideDialog();
        }
    });
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    AppController.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(request);


}
```

> I am able to get response in the LOG
>   `Log.e("onResponse",""+response);` But not able to set data to POJO.

**POJO CLASSES:**

**HighVelocityPojo.java**

```
 import java.util.List;
 import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
 import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class HighVelocityPojo {

    @SerializedName("SKU")
    @Expose
    private List<String> sKU = null;
    @SerializedName("wherehouse3")
    @Expose
    private Wherehouse3_HV wherehouse3;

    public List<String> getSKU() {
        return sKU;
    }

    public void setSKU(List<String> sKU) {
        this.sKU = sKU;
    }

    public Wherehouse3_HV getWherehouse3() {
        return wherehouse3;
    }

    public void setWherehouse3(Wherehouse3_HV wherehouse3) {
        this.wherehouse3 = wherehouse3;
    }

  }
```

**Wherehouse3_HV.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Wherehouse3_HV {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<Double> data = null;
    @SerializedName("qty")
    @Expose
    private Qty_HV qty;
    @SerializedName("cunsumption_time")
    @Expose
    private CunsumptionTime_HV cunsumptionTime;
    @SerializedName("sold_qty")
    @Expose
    private SoldQty_HV soldQty;
    @SerializedName("projected_inventry")
    @Expose
    private List<Integer> projectedInventry = null;
    @SerializedName("recived_inventry")
    @Expose
    private List<Integer> recivedInventry = null;
    @SerializedName("sku")
    @Expose
    private List<String> sku = null;
    @SerializedName("productname")
    @Expose
    private List<String> productname = null;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Double> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Double> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Qty_HV getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(Qty_HV qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public CunsumptionTime_HV getCunsumptionTime() {
        return cunsumptionTime;
    }

    public void setCunsumptionTime(CunsumptionTime_HV cunsumptionTime) {
        this.cunsumptionTime = cunsumptionTime;
    }

    public SoldQty_HV getSoldQty() {
        return soldQty;
    }

    public void setSoldQty(SoldQty_HV soldQty) {
        this.soldQty = soldQty;
    }

    public List<Integer> getProjectedInventry() {
        return projectedInventry;
    }

    public void setProjectedInventry(List<Integer> projectedInventry) {
        this.projectedInventry = projectedInventry;
    }

    public List<Integer> getRecivedInventry() {
        return recivedInventry;
    }

    public void setRecivedInventry(List<Integer> recivedInventry) {
        this.recivedInventry = recivedInventry;
    }

    public List<String> getSku() {
        return sku;
    }

    public void setSku(List<String> sku) {
        this.sku = sku;
    }

    public List<String> getProductname() {
        return productname;
    }

    public void setProductname(List<String> productname) {
        this.productname = productname;
    }

}
```

Comment: could you show your Wherehouse3_HV POJO too?

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I updated my question with **Wherehouse3_HV** POJO class.@LeviAlbuquerque

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to have a "list" key in your json, so this is yielding an error:

```
 String info = response.getString("list");
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(info);
```

Try to pass the response, like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<HighVelocityPojo>() {
}.getType();

HighVelocityPojo highVelocityPojo = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), listType);
Log.e("size", highVelocityPojo.getSKU().size() + "");
```

**Full code Here :**

```
private void JsonRequestGraph() {

    utils.showDialog();

    String url = Constants.TOP_10_BOUQUIT+"days="+time+"&warehouse_id="+whareHouse;
    Log.e("URL", "" + url);

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null,
            response -> {
                Log.e("onResponse",""+response);
                try {

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type listType = new TypeToken<HighVelocityPojo>() {
                    }.getType();

                    HighVelocityPojo highVelocityPojo = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), listType);
                    Log.e("size", highVelocityPojo.getSKU().size() + "");

                    callGraphView();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Exception",""+e);
                    utils.hideDialog();
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
               utils.hideDialog();

            }, error -> {

                Log.e("error",""+error.getMessage());
                utils.hideDialog();
            });
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    AppController.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(request);

}
```

Comment: Could i add my with my full Json Request code with your answer .@Pavya

Comment: Its ok.. no problem at all. HighVelocityPojo highVelocityPojo = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), listType); highVelocityPojo here you will get all data.